# Is it applicable to check equality with operator for SObject field values?

Tags: apex, sobject

Recently I was writing a code to check if sobject had changed values in fields. And I came across a question. Right now I have this code to check values diff:

```java
Object newValue = newRecord.get(fieldName);
Object oldValue = oldRecord.get(fieldName);
Boolean isValueChanged = (
    (oldValue == null && newValue != null) ||
    (oldValue != null && newValue == null) ||
    (oldValue != null && !oldValue.equals(newValue))
);
```

But my colleague wrote another check in another place this way:

```java
Object newValue = newRecord.get(fieldName);
Object oldValue = oldRecord.get(fieldName);
Boolean isValueChanged = newValue != oldValue;
```

Would it be working for all field values normally this way? I know Strings, numbers (Double, Decimal) and Date/Time are well comparable through `==` and `!=`, but still not sure if this solution has no bad use cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apex string comparisons using `==` and `!=` are case insensitive. That means that your colleague's code is not identical to your own. However, I do agree that you don't need the extra null checks. If you're looking for a case-sensitive comparison of strings, plus support for all other objects, consider:

```
Object oldValue = oldRecord.get(fieldName);
Object newValue = newRecord.get(fieldName);
Boolean isValueChanged = 
    oldValue?.equals(newValue) == false ||
    newValue?.equals(oldValue) == false ||
    ((oldValue instanceOf String || newValue instanceOf String) &&
     oldValue !== newValue);
```

The Safe Navigation Operator `?.` returns null if the left-hand operand is null, rather than throwing a `NullPointerException`. Thus, for all data types, `isValueChanged` will be false if both values are null or both values are not null and equal to each other, or true if just one of the values are null or the values are not equal to each other.

However, if you do not need this extra case-sensitive comparison, your colleague's code would be the shortest possible code that uses variables. For example, if you only care about the value changing, and not the value itself, it would be just as simple to write:

```
if(oldRecord.get(fieldName) != newRecord.get(fieldName)) {
  // ...
}
```

Here, we don't need to waste time with the variables, since each value is only used once.

Comment: Never knew that `==` comparison is case-insensitive, thank you!

Comment: Wait, I tried and got this:
```Object oldValue = 'a', newValue = 'b';
System.debug(oldValue?.equals(newValue) != newValue?.equals(oldValue));```
In that case `'a'.equals('b')` returns `false`, as well as `'b'.equals('a')`. Therefore, `isValueChanged` becomes `false` because `false != false => false`. So this method fails for both non-null different values.

Comment: @JackVeromeev Yeah, I think I actually meant `oldValue?.equals(newValue) == false ||  newValue?.equals(oldValue) == false`. I didn't think it all the way through apparently.

Comment: Thank you for the fixes! I didn't know that `?.` notation avoids NPE for method invocation, now my code will get much simpler :)